# Sequencer Video Export

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How can I export the best quality video file from Sequencer? I keep getting a color hue offset on the outputted video. In this example I have the Left, raw footage (pngs) and on the right the outputted video coming out orange.
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you just "output" your pngs or have you made some settings/filters/overlays in the video editor?

Comment: Can you check the Color Management in the Render Properties? It should be set to View Transform: Standard and not Filmic (which is the default color management setup if you start from a workspace other than the Video Editing Workspace.